# tabular inline admin where table are referenced in multiple tables

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I was looking on customizing admin where i found `tabularinline` model which allow us to edit on the same page. But i got confused as my tables are reference in multiple places. I could not understand which model should i make tabular inline.

for example here is my model

```
class ProductType(ModelWithMetadata):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, help_text="type of product. ex - accessories, apparel")
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, unique=True)
    is_shipping_required = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ("slug",)
        app_label="products"

class Category(MPTTModel, ModelWithMetadata):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=128)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        "self", null=True, blank=True, related_name="children", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    
    objects = models.Manager()
    tree = TreeManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Category"
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Product(ModelWithMetadata, PublishableModel):
    product_type = models.ForeignKey(
        ProductType, related_name="products", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        Category,
        related_name="products",
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    isAvailable = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    isDiscount = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    charge_taxes = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "product"
        verbose_name_plural = "products"
        ordering = ("name",)
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=["article_number", "slug"], name="unique article number and slug")
        ]

class ProductVariant(ModelWithMetadata):
    sku = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    currency = models.CharField(
        max_length=settings.DEFAULT_CURRENCY_CODE_LENGTH,
        default=settings.DEFAULT_CURRENCY,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
    price_override_amount = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=settings.DEFAULT_MAX_DIGITS,
        decimal_places=settings.DEFAULT_DECIMAL_PLACES,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
    product = models.ForeignKey(
        Product, related_name="variants", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    images = models.ManyToManyField("ProductImage", through="VariantImage")
    track_inventory = models.BooleanField(default=True)


class BaseAssignedAttribute(models.Model):

    assignment = None
    values = models.ManyToManyField("AttributeValue")


class AttributeValue(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default="")
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255)
    attribute = models.ForeignKey(
        "Attribute", related_name="values", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )


class AssignedProductAttribute(BaseAssignedAttribute):
    """Associate a product type attribute and selected values to a given product."""

    product = models.ForeignKey(
        Product, related_name="attributes", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    assignment = models.ForeignKey(
        "ProductAttribute", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="productassignments"
    )

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("product", "assignment"),)


class AssignedVariantAttribute(BaseAssignedAttribute):
    """Associate a product type attribute and selected values to a given variant."""

    variant = models.ForeignKey(
        ProductVariant, related_name="attributes", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    assignment = models.ForeignKey(
        "AttributeVariant", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="variantassignments"
    )

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("variant", "assignment"),)


class AttributeVariant(models.Model):
    attribute = models.ForeignKey(
        "Attribute", related_name="attributevariant", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    product_type = models.ForeignKey(
        ProductType, related_name="attributevariant", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    assigned_variants = models.ManyToManyField(
        ProductVariant,
        blank=True,
        through=AssignedVariantAttribute,
        through_fields=("assignment", "variant"),
        related_name="attributesrelated",
    )


class Attribute(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    product_types = models.ManyToManyField(
        ProductType,
        blank=True,
        related_name="product_attributes",
        through="ProductAttribute",
        through_fields=("attribute", "product_type"),
    )
    product_variant_types = models.ManyToManyField(
        ProductType,
        blank=True,
        related_name="variant_attributes",
        through=AttributeVariant,
        through_fields=("attribute", "product_type"),
    )


class ProductAttribute(models.Model):
    attribute = models.ForeignKey(
        "Attribute", related_name="attributeproduct", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    product_type = models.ForeignKey(
        ProductType, related_name="attributeproduct", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    assigned_products = models.ManyToManyField(
        Product,
        blank=True,
        through=AssignedProductAttribute,
        through_fields=("assignment", "product"),
        related_name="attributesrelated",
    )
```

I am confused on the tables `AttributeValue`, `AssignedProductAttribute`, `AssignedVariantAttribute`, `AttributeVariant`, `Attribute` and `ProductAttribute`. Attribute is related to ProductAttribute and is also related to AttributeVariant and AttributeValue. Similarly, in the case of variant.

I could not figure out which table should be inline and where should i reference that inlined table. Because of various relationship, i am not sure of those things.